# Separate Mediawiki Theme for Its Front Page

Tags: mediawiki

Is there any way to use a different theme file for a Mediawiki's front page, while the rest of the wiki uses the standard theme you set? For example, say I use Monobook.php for all of my regular pages, but Custom.php for my wiki's front page. I can't find anything that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. All you need to do is use a hook, check if the current `$wgTitle` is the same as the main page title, and if it is, switch the Skin object to a different skin.

The hook you should use for this is [`RequestContextCreateSkin`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/RequestContextCreateSkin).

The `Skin` object is passed by reference there, so you should have no trouble replacing it with a custom skin of your choice.

Good luck.

Comment: `BeforePageDisplay` might be a little late to change the skin.  I'd suggest [`RequestContextCreateSkin`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/RequestContextCreateSkin) instead.

Comment: Good point. Edited answer.